# Custom CheckBox Content is not visible

Tags: c#, wpf

I just stared with C# WPF applications and i've made a custom checkbox. Problem is that checkbox border can only have 1 child, so i have to put path and contentPresenter into grid. My problem is that content(checkbox text) is not visible... Thanks for help.

This is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Moire Light" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Width="15" Height="15" Background="Purple">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        />
                        <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                          Width="8"
                          Height="8"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 M 0 8 L 8 0"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Stroke="Yellow"
                          StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                          StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                          StrokeThickness="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DockPanel` instead:

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Width="15" Height="15" Background="Purple"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                                <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                                          Width="8"
                                          Height="8"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 M 0 8 L 8 0"
                                          Stretch="Fill"
                                          Stroke="Yellow"
                                          StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                                          StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                                          StrokeThickness="1" />
                            </Border>

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                        </DockPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `CheckBox` :

[image]

There were a few things incorrect, no trigger when control is checked, visibility should be hidden rather than collapsed. Also I've defined the content alignment to use values from the template as in the original `CheckBox`

Note : I've used a grid column with an auto width but @HighCore is right, a DockPanel is even better.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="myCheckBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Moire Light" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1"  Background="Purple">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                            Width="8"
                            Height="8"
                            Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 M 0 8 L 8 0"
                            Stretch="Fill"
                            Stroke="Yellow"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                            StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                            StrokeThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="2" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CheckMark" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CheckMark" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid  >
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="58.31" Width="141.317" IsChecked="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource myCheckBoxStyle}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43.31" Margin="334,95.935,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="34,89,0,0" Height="58.31" Width="141.317" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource myCheckBoxStyle}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43.31" Margin="349,16.935,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Additionally, I'd highly suggest you to edit your templates in Blend, it makes the thing much easier.

Comment: like @Sheridan said... +1 for making the effort with the image

Comment: @TheMatto... yeah, but I actually up voted the post, rather than just saying +1.